# Explain the number of bits in a hash value that features both numbers and letters

Tags: string, hash, byte, bit

I need some help understanding this concept:
If I have a 256-bit hash, the value is essentially a 64-character long string. This is because each character is 4-bits long (64*4 = 256), correct? However, along with numbers letters are also used in hash values, and letters are 8-bits long. Doesn't a 64-character long hash key that features letters along with numbers ultimately create a hash value that is greater than 256-bits?

Take this hash value for example: `7833dc6e82e9378117bcb03128ac8fdd95d9073161ebc963783b3010dd847ff3`

It is 64-characters long, but the letter d is 8-bits long rather than 4. So how does this hash count as 256-bits?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letters aren't *really* letters. You've probably noticed that the only included alphabet characters are A-F. This is because the hash is using base 16 ([hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)) numbering.

Unlike base 10 where the valid characters are 0-9, in base 16, there are sixteen valid characters: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F`. `16 = 2^4`, so you need 4 bits for each character.